# Top clock panel in Ubuntu

Tags: cairo-dock

I am using Ubuntu with cairo-dock without unity, but I want top clock-panel, how I can install it in my desktop?

Comment: Mean of "top clock-panel" to you? I see there are a digital clock on top-right corner in Cairo Desktop Environment.
Can you see it?

Answer (score 1):

If you install the "cairo-dock" and "cairo-dock-plug-ins" packages you should get a preset theme called Default-Panel that will give you a panel with a clock at the top (as well as a dock at the bottom).

Comment: Oh, thats, gooood.

Comment: but I lost my files on my desktop :(

Comment: @NadirNovruzov That's another problem. Don't hesitate to use [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) in this case. If this answered your question, you may [mark this answer as accepted](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers), by clicking the green check mark next to it. That will indicate that your problem is solved.